# My Visual Studio 2017 debug start button showing disabled

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2017, developer-tools

[image]

How can this be fixed? Program is unusable for me without this feature

Comment: Maybe your cursor is posessed in a point where trace have no sense?

Comment: Do you have a solution open or just a file?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch hit that right on the head.  You need to make a c/c++ project and work from that.  Also..  you shouldn't be running visual studio as an administrator.